# PowerShell: What is the best method for parallel execution of commands with logging

Tags: powershell

I have a vendor provided application that needs to be run once with each of several locally stored configuration files. I have tried two different methods to run these commands in parallel, one is slower but seems to work fine, the second seems faster but I get no logs so I can't confirm that the application is actually being executed.

This first method is definitely running parallel. It is much faster than the old procedural version. So that is great.:

```
$configList = $(Get-ChildItem E:\Path\*config.ps1 -recurse).FullName
$configList | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    # Get the config and logfile path for each
    . $_
    Invoke-expression "& E:\dir\app.exe $config"  | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfile
}
```

From my reading I understand that using a RunspacePool can be even faster, and this does execute faster, but it is producing no entries in my logs so I can't ensure it is running properly. Any help is appreciated.

```
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Jobs = @()
$configList = $(Get-ChildItem E:\Path\*config.ps1 -recurse).FullName
$configList | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the config and logfile path for each
    . $_
    $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
    $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    $PowerShell.AddScript({Invoke-expression "& E:\dir\app.exe $config" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfile})
    $Jobs += $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
}
```

Comment: I have no understanding of how runspaces work, but the problem with the second example could be an issue with variable scope. Rather than sourcing the config outside the script block, you may need to pass it to it. `$PowerShell.AddScript({param([string]$config); . $config; Invoke-expression "& E:\dir\app.exe" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfile}).AddParameter("config", $_)`

Comment: Thanks, this got me pointed in the right direction. I do think it was a scoping issue. It is still not quite working but I think I am close with: `$PowerShell.AddScript({param([string]$cmd,[string]$logfile); Invoke-expression "& $cmd" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfile}).AddParameter("cmd", $cmd).AddParameter("logfile", $logfile)`